# What is the best way to get cell index of a word table without using for loop in c#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, ms-word, xceed

I am getting the index of the cell of a word table using for loop which takes a lot of time for bigger tables, is there any way to do this without for loop?

```
public static int[] GetColumnIndex(Xceed.Words.NET.Table table, string columnName, int endRow,int k)
        {
            int[] data = { -1, -1 };
            for (int j = k; j < endRow; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows[j].Cells.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (table.Rows[j].Cells[i].Paragraphs[0].Text.Equals("«" + columnName + "»"))
                    {
                        data[0] = j;
                        data[1] = i;
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
```

and I am calling this function form another function

```
int startRow = 0, endRow = 0;
int[] ind;
DocX doc;
doc = DocX.Load(fileName);
Xceed.Words.NET.Table t;
t = doc.Tables[0];
endRow = t.Rows.Count;
System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = reader(report.Query);
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    ind = GetColumnIndex(t, col.ColumnName, endRow,2);

    //...more code here...
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Firstly, I'm not familiar with XCeed so I may be missing something.  However, you seem to have a DataTable with column names and a function called "GetColumnIndex" to which you are passing a column name from the DataTable. You might expect this to return the index of the column that has the same column name, however, you are looking through the entire table to find the cell that has the same content as the column header. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Secondly you are looping through all the columns and calling this function for every column in the datatable - the only call that is valid is the last one as you overwrite the ind variable each time

Comment: Can you try and clear up exactly what it is you are trying to achieve and make the above code make sense, someone may then be able to answer your question

Comment: I am trying to populate word table using datatable. First I search column header in word table that is available in datatable as well then I fill all the rows of that column from datatable to word table.

Comment: there is more code in foreach loop that populate data into table but I did not show it because of no need ... I only want fastest method to get cell index or any other way of doing this...

Comment: The way you have written the GetColumnIndex function and are calling it, you are searching from row 2 to the end row in every cell for a column header.  i.e. you are searching every cell for the column header in every row except the first one.  Is this really correct?

Comment: I have placed my header in the 2nd row so it does not matter

Comment: ok so why then are you searching the entire table if your headers are in the second row?  Just seach the second row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you can do to optimise your algorithm (based on your access pattern) is that you search the same table number of times (in fact, since you are searching column names in the table, number of searches increases quickly as the table gets big). Hence, it would be worth transforming the data in the table to a data structure indexed by the words (for e.g. a [Sorted Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)).

Firstly, create a class that holds the content of the table. This way when you want to search the same table, you can use the same instance of the class and avoid recreating the data structure based on the sorted dictionary:

```
public class XceedTableAdapter
{
   private readonly SortedDictionary<string, (int row, int column)> dict;

   public XceedTableAdapter(Xceed.Words.NET.Table table)
   {
      this.dict = new SortedDictionary<string, (int, int)>();
      // Copy the content of the table into the dict.
      // If you have duplicate words you need a SortedDictionary<string, List<(int, int)>> type. This is not clear in your question.
      for (var i = 0, i < rowCount; i++)
      {
          for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
          {
              // this will overwrite the index if the text was previously found: 
              this.dict[table.Rows[i].Cells[j].Paragraphs[0].Text] = (i, j);
          }
      }
   }

   public (int, int) GetColumnIndex(string searchText)
   {
      if(this.dict.TryGetValue(searchText, out var index))
      {
          return index;
      }

      return (-1, -1);
   }
}
```

Now you loop the entire table only once and the subsequent searches will happen in O(log n). If Xceed has a function to transform data table to a dictionary, that would be quite handy. I'm not familiar with this library.

Now you can search it like:

```
var searchableTable = new XceedTableAdapter(doc.Tables[0]);

foreach (var col in dt.Columns)
{
   ind = searchableTable.GetColumnIndex(col);
}
```

Comment: thereby duplicating the entire table in memory and shifting all the cpu load up a couple of lines to where you create the XceedTableAdaptor - large tables were mentioned.

Comment: @TimRutter That depends on the way you use the original table. In my solution, I do not hold a reference to the original table letting it be gc-ed in time. Besides, even if you had to, for some reason, you gotta choose to pay a price. Unsorted table indexed by rows and columns is just not good enough for frequent searches.

Comment: I guess if there are a great many calls to GetColumnIndex it will reduce the workload there.